# What are the solutions to $x^2+7=y^3$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

What are the integer solutions to $x^2+7=y^3$?

I think that this would require algebraic number theory using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is a unique factorization domain, but I don't know enough number theory to proceed.

The only integer solutions, according to SAGE is $$(\pm 1, 2) (\pm 181, 32)$$

Comment: $ \mathbf Z[\sqrt{-7}] $ is not a unique factorization domain - it is not even integrally closed.

Comment: $(\pm 1,2)$ and $(\pm 181,32)$ are the solutions. (and consider elliptic curves to try to get others).

Comment: @Oleg567 How did you find the solutions?I could not find any by plotting the graphs....they don't intersect...

Comment: @tatan: simply considered sequence $\{y^3-7\} = \{..., 1, 20, 57, ..., 32761, ...\}$ and checked whether each term is the square number.

Comment: @Oleg567 Did you run a Python program?Thanks btw...

Comment: @tatan: C++ yet; but these small numbers can be checked even in Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @Starfall I admit I know little about algebraic number theory, but this is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number) seems to say in it's article about Heegner numbers. $7$ is a Heegner number, so the article seems to be saying that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is a unique factorization domain.

Comment: $ 7 $ is a Heegner number, which means that the ring of integers of $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-7}) $ is a unique factorization domain. Unfortunately, this ring of integers is not $ \mathbf Z[\sqrt{-7}] $.

Comment: Please give us some context: this is called a "Mordell equation", and the only integer solutions are the ones indicated by @Oleg567. Are you supposed to solve it by elementary means? This might not be feasible.

Comment: @AlexM. I wanted another answer to the question given on another site, name [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-integer-solutions-to-x-2+7-y-3).